# Finding files that are not checked into repo

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops, visual-studio-2019, tfvc

Is there an easy way to find files that are not checked into my repository in my Visual Studio project?

In the past, there's been times when I get my code base from the repo only to realize that some files -- for some reason -- had not been checked into the repository.

I recently got a new laptop and downloaded the code for my app onto my new machine. I'm now getting an error when I run the app on the new laptop but on the old one it runs perfectly fine. My first thought was that there were configuration differences between two machines so I downloaded the code into a new folder on the old machine and started having the same error that I'm having on the new laptop. If I run the app from the original folder on the old machine, it runs fine.

This makes me think that I may have some differences in the code between what's on the repo and the original folder. As a result, if I get the code from the repo, I have the error. If I try to check in the code from the original folder on the old laptop, Visual Studio tells me that there's nothing to check in.

So, is there an easy way for me to see if there's any file that is not checked into the repo on my old laptop?

BTW, I'm running Visual Studio 2019 -- with the latest updates/patches -- and my repo is on Azure DevOps and uses TFVC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running `tf vc status /format:detailed /recursive` from a Visual Studio Developer Commandline in your workspace root should give you a good overview of files not checked in and files with pending changes.

```
C:\Users\JesseHouwing\source\Workspaces\xxx>tf vc status /format:detailed /recursive
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Detected Changes:
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
$/xxx/test.txt
  User       : Jesse Houwing
  Date       : zaterdag 27 juli 2019 21:20:00
  Lock       : none
  Change     : add
  Workspace  : SHARKIE
  Local item : [SHARKIE] C:\Users\JesseHouwing\Source\Workspaces\xxx\test.txt

0 change(s), 1 detected change(s)
```

It should auto-detect files unless you specify the `/nodetectchanges` flag.

Or, if your `.tfignore` file is well specified, you can run `tf vc add * /recursive` to automatically create a pending change for all files that are currently not under version control. [If needed, edit your `tfignore` file before running the add command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/add-files-server?view=azure-devops#customize-which-files-are-ignored-by-version-control). Add `/noignore` to bypass the ignore file, but that may add `bin` and `obj` and `packages` folders as well, be careful.

---

`tf.exe` is hidden deep in the bowels of Visual Studio, easiest way to get access to it is to use the Developer Command Prompt:

[image]

My installation has put it here:

```
C:\Users\JesseHouwing\source\Workspaces\xxx>where tf
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\TF.exe
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I don't seem to have `tf.exe` on my computer. Getting the `tf is not recognized as an internal or external command` error. I Google'd it and it suggested I specify the path to `tf.exe` but it's not on my computer at all. What do I need to install to run this command?

Comment: Thanks again for your response. I got it to work and the results are absolutely SCARY! Some 33,520 files are not in the repo. Most of them are not terribly important such as license file of an NPM package BUT there are some legitimate `cs` files in my ASP.NET Core project are NOT checked into the repo. I want to tackle the issue first and then I'll look into why this is happening. What's the easiest way to check these files into the repo? For example, I see class file I created in C#. Next to it, there's no icon associated with my repo -- meaning VS maybe thinking it's not part of the project.

Comment: Just right clicked the missing class file i.e. `ReviewerDao.cs` and in the context menu, I get the option to "exclude" it from the project so clearly it's part of the project. I also get an option that reads "Add files to source control". Not sure why it's not included in the source control in the first place. As I said, the first thing to do is to include them in the repo. What's the easiest way to add them to source control?

Comment: Actually, I see that in your answer, you were kind enough to answer my question.

Comment: Actually, in my repo, I don't see the `node_modules` at all so I don't think it's being checked in. However, my C# class file is in my project folder and it definitely should've been checked in. Not sure why it's ignored.